# Good forcings with bad squares

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

[Consistently with $\mathsf{ZFC}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853079/28111) there is a forcing which preserves cardinals but whose square does not *always* preserve cardinals - that is, some $\mathbb{P}$ such that for every $\mathbb{P}$-generic $G$ we have $\mathrm{Card}^{V}=\mathrm{Card}^{V[G]}$ but for some $\mathbb{P}^2$-generic $H=\langle H_0,H_1\rangle$ we have $\mathrm{Card}^{V}\not=\mathrm{Card}^{V[H]}$.

However, the only way I know how to get this is via a bit of a cheat: find two *different* forcings which are individually "good" but have "bad" product, and then look at their lottery sum. This construction has the drawback that the square of the resulting forcing doesn't always collapse cardinals - we're only guaranteed "bad" behavior in the extension if the two coordinates of our generic lie on different "sides" of the original lottery sum.

I recall$^*$ seeing a stronger example of this phenomenon, but I can't track it down or reconstruct it on my own:

> Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there is a forcing $\mathbb{P}$ such that $\mathbb{P}$ preserves cardinals but $\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}^2}\mathrm{Card}^V\not=\mathrm{Card}^{V[\langle H_0,H_1\rangle]}$?

---

$^*$Actually my *original* memory was that even the weaker phenomenon can't happen, but after it was pointed out to me that it can, I now remember differently. I'm sure eventually my memory will have been right. :P

Comment: Consistently? Sure. Suslin trees are ccc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does forcing with the square of a Suslin tree (always) collapse cardinals? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I believe so, because $T\times T$ will collapse $\omega_1$. But now I'm not sure. But I'm pretty sure that it is at least consistently the case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, I don't see that $T\times T$ need collapse $\omega_1$. I wouldn't be surprised if it were consistently the case, but I don't see it.

Comment: I mean, $T\times T$ definitely has a condition that collapses $\omega_1$. If $T$ is homogeneous, that should be enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I'm not seeing it - why does there need to be such a condition?

Comment: I may be misremembering. Let's see what someone more knowledgeable says.

Comment: Will a self-specializing Souslin Tree do the trick here?

Comment: @ToddEisworth Yup, that looks like it does it! (I didn't know such things existed, they're neat - thanks for bringing them to my attention.) If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I only know about them through Mathoverflow!

Comment: It seems obligatory to give the example of Todocevic square: if $\mathbb{S}$ adds a generic $\square(\kappa)$ for $\kappa$ regular, and $\mathbb{T}$ is the threading forcing, then $\mathbb{S} \ast \mathbb{T}$ is equivalent to the $\kappa$-Cohen forcing while $\mathbb{S} \ast (\mathbb{T}^2)$ collapses $\kappa$ to be countable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A self-specializing Souslin tree gives you a ccc notion of forcing whose square collapses $\omega_1$ (See, e.g.,  the answer to
[Ultrafilters preserved by $\mathbb{P}$ but not by products?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251930/ultrafilters-preserved-by-mathbbp-but-not-by-products)). Such trees exist under $\diamondsuit$, and so are consistent with ZFC.

Answer (score 9):

One can indeed prove more: starting with $V=L$, there exists a tame and cardinal preserving class forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ such that forcing with $\mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P}$ collapses
all uncountable cardinals. See

- Adam Figura, *Collapsing algebras and Suslin trees*, Fundamenta Mathematicae **114** (1981) 141-147, doi:[10.4064/fm-114-2-141-147](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-114-2-141-147).

Comment: Very cool! (I've made a minor clarifying edit.)